# Set QGroupBox title font size with style sheets

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qtstylesheets

I would like to be able to set the font size of the title of a QGroupBox using style sheets.  I can't seem to figure it out.

Based on what I've read [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/stylesheet-examples.html#id-bfd71794-8c48-4cff-a7bf-d5fe48e62558), I've come up with the following code.  Unfortunately, it doesn't quite work.

```
groupbox->setStyleSheet(style)
```

Where `style` is:

```
QGroupBox::title
{
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
    subcontrol-position: top left;
    padding: 5 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

All of those style elements seem to be honored except `font-size` and `font-weight`.  According to the [Qt Style Sheets Reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/stylesheet-reference.html), the font "property is supported by all widgets that respect the QWidget::font."  Is this not the case for a QGroupBox's title?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The answer is "no", the title of a `QGroupBox` does not support the `QWidget::font` property. I suspect that the title is not an independant `QWidget` but a part of the `QGroupBox` widget (thus drawn by the `QGroupBox::paint()`).

However, the `GroupBox` widget supports the font property and since the only text displayed by a group box is its title, you can apply your font style to the `QGroupBox` widget.

```
QGroupBox
{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```